# What is the difference between "was living" and "lived?"

Tags: grammar

I want to know the difference between these two sentences:

> I was living in this town for 2 years.
>
> I lived in this town for 2 years.

Answer (score 2):

> I lived in this town for 2 years.

This is simple past- the normal way of saying that, at some time in the past, you lived in the town where you are now, but you no longer live there.

> I was living in this town for 2 years.

This sentence is past continuous: it is understandable but it is not natural, because it contains a past continuous **and** it specifies a **time interval**.
Normally, when you use past continuous, you specify an event, a date or a time that the continuous activity includes:

> I was living in this town **when I first met my girlfriend**.
>   I was living in this town **when the Berlin wall came down**.
>   I was living in this town **in 2015**

Comment: I was living in this town during the nineties. this sentence includes a time interval. And dose it means that I wasn't leaving this town during this period?

Comment: @yangliu it means that you were living in this town **at some time** during that decade. It does not give any indication of how long you lived there. You could have started living there before or after that decade started, and could have moved somewhere else before or after the decade ended.