# I have swum in this river. I have been swimming in this river. What is the difference?

Tags: grammar

I have swum in this pool every afternoon. this sentence means that I do not swim in this pool now and I won't swim in the pool. But I have been swimming in this pool every afternoon which means I still do this in the pool every afternoon. What is the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i was living in this town for 2 years. i lived in this town for 2 years. what is the difference?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/228623/i-was-living-in-this-town-for-2-years-i-lived-in-this-town-for-2-years-what-is)

Answer (score 1):

There is very little difference.  A tiny variation in nuance indicating if you view the swim as happening at one or more *points* in time in the past, or for one or more *periods* of time in the past.

In most contexts this doesn't make any difference, and so either is possible, and the slightly shorter "I have swum" would be preferred.

> I have swum in this river, but I have never fished here.
>
> I love swimming. I've been swimming in this river and it was a lot of fun

In the second case I'm talking about an activity that took a period of time. But in either of the above examples you could use both "have swum" or "have been swimming".

In some situations you are talking about a period of time.

> I've been swimming in this river for the last 30 minutes and I haven't seen a single fish.

In this example "I've swum" would be correct, but it is natural to use "been swimming".